# Return the Row Index with the minimum sum in a two dimensional list Python

Tags: python

I am using a two dimensional list in python, I need to find the sum of every item in the list and then return the index with the lowest value.

It should return like this:

```
Row([[1000, 30], [12, 23], [560, 30, 1]])
1
Row([[10, 9], [20, 1, 2], [1, 3]])
2
```

This is what I have so far in the shell:

```
def Row(S):
count=0
for r in range(len(S[0])):
    for c in range(len(S)):
        count += sum([r])
        return r
```

I can't get the code in the shell to return the indice in a two dimensional list with the lowest sum. Any ideas?

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 1 line:

```
minidx = min(enumerate(data), key=lambda x:sum(x[1]))[0]
```

Although I would prefer to do the unpacking (instead of indexing the result):

```
minidx, minlist = min(enumerate(data), key=lambda x:sum(x[1]))
```

This has the side benefit that you get a quick handle on the list which has the minimum sum ... Although that's easy enough to get once you have the index ...

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a "key" to `min` to get the minimum of a list according to some arbitrary criteria. Using this feature, we can do it in just one line:

```
def min_sum(data):
    return min(xrange(len(data)), key=lambda i: sum(data[i]))
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1).  basically the same as mine.  I like to avoid `xrange(len(data))`, but then I also like to avoid `lambda x:sum(x[1])`.  I'm not sure which is better ...

Comment: if you don't mind throwing numpy in the mix, you can use `np.argmin` to avoid the lambda

Comment: @wim -- I'm not sure I follow your numpy solution.  If the sublists were all the same length, I think I would agree, but I don't see how to do it since they're not all the same length. (But, as always, If you have a numpy solution, please post so I and others can learn)

Comment: it would be like `np.argmin(sum(x) for x in data)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def row(data):
    sums = [sum(x) for x in data]
    return sums.index(min(sums))

print row([[1000, 30], [12, 23], [560, 30, 1]])
```